# DataTable cannot DataBind() to GridView (after sucessfully deleting a row from DataTable)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am successfully able to delete the row from the DataTable from Modal Popup Extender button click event at ButtonOk_Click().

But showing error when DataBind() again to GridView at ButtonOk_Click()

I am receiving ERROR at below line in CustomersGridView_RowDataBound 
if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[10].Text) == 0)

May be because e.Row.Cells[10].Text is not getting value appropriately when data bound after deleting.

### ASPX Page

```html
<asp:ScriptManagerID="ScriptManager1"runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:GridViewID="grdOrgListData"runat="server"AllowPaging="True"AutoGenerateColumns="False"onrowdatabound="CustomersGridView_RowDataBound"
CssClass="tabletable-bordered"OnPageIndexChanging="grdOrgListData_PageIndexChanging">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundFieldDataField="OrgID"HeaderText="ID"/>
<asp:BoundFieldDataField="OrgName"HeaderText="Name"ReadOnly="True"/>
<asp:BoundFieldDataField="OrgDescription"HeaderText="Description"/>
<asp:BoundFieldDataField="OrgAddress"HeaderText="Address"/>
<asp:BoundFieldDataField="OrgZipCode"HeaderText="ZipCode"/>
<asp:BoundFieldDataField="OrgCountry"HeaderText="Country"ReadOnly="True"/>
<asp:BoundFieldDataField="OrgEmail"HeaderText="Email"ReadOnly="True"/>
<asp:BoundFieldDataField="OrgPhoneNo"HeaderText="PhoneNo"/>
<asp:BoundFieldDataField="OrgWebsite"HeaderText="Website"ReadOnly="True"/>
<asp:BoundFieldDataField="EmailID"HeaderText="OwnerEmail"/>
<asp:BoundFieldDataField="ActiveStatus"HeaderText="ActiveStatus"/>

<asp:TemplateFieldHeaderText="Actions">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButtonrunat="server"ID="imgBtnView"OnClick="imgBtnView_Click"/>
<asp:ImageButtonrunat="server"ID="imgBtnEdit"OnClick="imgBtnEdit_Click"/>
<asp:ImageButtonrunat="server"ID="imgBtnDelete"OnClick="imgBtnDelete_Click"/>
<asp:ImageButtonrunat="server"ID="imgBtnActive"OnClick="imgBtnActive_Click"/>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

<editrowstyleBackColor="#999999"></editrowstyle>
<footerstyleBackColor="#5D7B9D"Font-Bold="True"ForeColor="White"></footerstyle>
<headerstyleBackColor="#5D7B9D"Font-Bold="True"ForeColor="White"></headerstyle>

<rowstyleBackColor="#F7F6F3"ForeColor="#333333"></rowstyle>
<selectedrowstyleBackColor="#E2DED6"Font-Bold="True"ForeColor="#333333"></selectedrowstyle>
<sortedascendingcellstyleBackColor="#E9E7E2"></sortedascendingcellstyle>

<pagersettingsmode="Numeric"position="Bottom"pagebuttoncount="10"/>
<pagerstyleHorizontalAlign="right"CssClass="pagination-ys"/>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:ButtonID="btnShowPopupView"runat="server"style="display:none"/>
<asp:ButtonID="btnShowPopupDelete"runat="server"style="display:none"/>

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtenderID="ModalPopupExtender1"runat="server"TargetControlID="btnShowPopupView"Drag="true"
PopupControlID="PNLView"OkControlID="ButtonClose"BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"/>

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtenderID="ModalPopupExtender2"runat="server"TargetControlID="btnShowPopupDelete"Drag="true"
PopupControlID="PNLDelete"OkControlID="ButtonOk"CancelControlID="ButtonCancel"BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"/>

<asp:PanelID="PNLView"runat="server"Style="display:none;width:350px;background-color:White;border-width:2px;border-color:Black;border-style:solid;padding:20px;">
OrgID:<asp:LabelID="lblOrgID"runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
OrgName:<asp:LabelID="lblOrgName"runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
Desciption:<asp:LabelID="lblOrgDescription"runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
MailAddress:<asp:LabelID="lblOrgAddress"runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
ZipCode:<asp:LabelID="lblOrgZipCode"runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
Country:<asp:LabelID="lblOrgCountry"runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
Email:<asp:LabelID="lblOrgEmail"runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
PhoneNo:<asp:LabelID="lblOrgPhoneNo"runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
Website:<asp:LabelID="lblOrgWebsite"runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
OwnerEmail:<asp:LabelID="lblOwnerEmail"runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
ActiveStatus:<asp:LabelID="lblActiveStatus"runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<divstyle="text-align:right;">
<asp:ButtonID="ButtonClose"runat="server"Text="Close"CssClass="btnbtn-smbtn-primarym-t-n-xs"/>
</div>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:PanelID="PNLDelete"runat="server"Style="display:none;width:300px;background-color:White;border-width:2px;border-color:Black;border-style:solid;padding:20px;">
OrgName:<asp:LabelID="lblOrgDelete"runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br/>
Doyouwanttodeletethisorganisation?
<br/>
<br/>
<divstyle="text-align:right;">
<asp:ButtonID="ButtonOk"runat="server"Text="OK"CssClass="btnbtn-smbtn-primarym-t-n-xs"
OnClick="ButtonOk_Click"UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
<asp:ButtonID="ButtonCancel"runat="server"Text="Cancel"CssClass="btnbtn-smbtn-primarym-t-n-xs"/>
</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

===========================================

### CS Page

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;

namespace PseudoExam.AdminPanel
{
    public partial class Organisation : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void btnAdd_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server.Transfer("/AdminPanel/Organisation.Add.aspx");
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                LoadGridData();
        }

        private void LoadGridData()
        {
            string strOrgAdminIDs = Convert.ToString(Session["OrgAdminIDs"]);

            DataTable ds = DBOperations.GetOrgDataset(strOrgAdminIDs);
            ds.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ds.Columns["OrgID"] };
            string strLabel = "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 records";
            Session["OrgDataSet"] = ds;

            if (ds != null)
            {
                if (ds.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    grdOrgListData.DataSource = ds;
                    grdOrgListData.DataBind();
                    grdOrgListData.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                    grdOrgListData.Columns[2].Visible = false;
                    grdOrgListData.Columns[3].Visible = false;
                    grdOrgListData.Columns[4].Visible = false;
                    grdOrgListData.Columns[7].Visible = false;
                    grdOrgListData.Columns[9].Visible = false;
                    grdOrgListData.Columns[10].Visible = false;

                    if (ds.Rows.Count > 0 && ds.Rows.Count > 9)
                        strLabel = "Showing 1 to 10 of " + ds.Rows.Count + " records";
                    else if (ds.Rows.Count > 0 && ds.Rows.Count <= 9)
                        strLabel = "Showing 1 to " + ds.Rows.Count + " of " + ds.Rows.Count + " records";
                }
                else
                {
                    grdOrgListData.DataSource = null;
                    grdOrgListData.DataBind();
                }
            }

            lblRecordStatus.Text = strLabel;
        }

        protected void grdOrgListData_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            ds = (DataTable)Session["OrgDataSet"];
            string strLabel = "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 records";

            if (ds != null)
            {
                grdOrgListData.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
                grdOrgListData.DataSource = ds;
                grdOrgListData.DataBind();

                if (ds.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    int intFrom = (e.NewPageIndex * 10) + 1;
                    int intTo = (e.NewPageIndex * 10) + 10;

                    if (intFrom == ds.Rows.Count)
                        strLabel = "Showing " + intFrom + " to " + ds.Rows.Count + " of " + ds.Rows.Count + " records";
                    else if (intFrom < ds.Rows.Count && intTo >= ds.Rows.Count)
                        strLabel = "Showing " + intFrom + " to " + ds.Rows.Count + " of " + ds.Rows.Count + " records";
                    else if (intFrom < ds.Rows.Count && intTo < ds.Rows.Count)
                        strLabel = "Showing " + intFrom + " to " + intTo + " of " + ds.Rows.Count + " records";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                grdOrgListData.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
                grdOrgListData.DataSource = null;
                grdOrgListData.DataBind();
            }

            lblRecordStatus.Text = strLabel;
        }

        protected void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            int intUserRole = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserRole"]);

            if ((intUserRole == 0) || (intUserRole == 1))
            {

                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    ImageButton PlaceHolderView1 = e.Row.FindControl("imgBtnView") as ImageButton;
                    PlaceHolderView1.ImageUrl = "../images/system/View_B.png";

                    ImageButton PlaceHolderView2 = e.Row.FindControl("imgBtnEdit") as ImageButton;
                    PlaceHolderView2.ImageUrl = "../images/system/Edit_B.png";

                    MessageBox.Show("e.Row.Cells[] = " + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + " ,= " + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + " ,= " + e.Row.Cells[2].Text + " ,= " + e.Row.Cells[10].Text);
                   
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[10].Text) == 0)
                    {
                        ImageButton PlaceHolderView3 = e.Row.FindControl("imgBtnDelete") as ImageButton;
                        PlaceHolderView3.ImageUrl = "../images/system/Delete_G.png";
                        PlaceHolderView3.Enabled = false;

                        ImageButton PlaceHolderView4 = e.Row.FindControl("imgBtnActive") as ImageButton;
                        PlaceHolderView4.ImageUrl = "../images/system/Play_B.png";
                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[10].Text) == 1)
                    {
                        ImageButton PlaceHolderView3 = e.Row.FindControl("imgBtnDelete") as ImageButton;
                        PlaceHolderView3.ImageUrl = "../images/system/Delete_B.png";

                        ImageButton PlaceHolderView4 = e.Row.FindControl("imgBtnActive") as ImageButton;
                        PlaceHolderView4.ImageUrl = "../images/system/Play_G.png";
                        PlaceHolderView4.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[10].Text) == 2)
                    {
                        ImageButton PlaceHolderView3 = e.Row.FindControl("imgBtnDelete") as ImageButton;
                        PlaceHolderView3.ImageUrl = "../images/system/Delete_G.png";
                        PlaceHolderView3.Enabled = false;

                        ImageButton PlaceHolderView4 = e.Row.FindControl("imgBtnActive") as ImageButton;
                        PlaceHolderView4.ImageUrl = "../images/system/Play_G.png";
                        PlaceHolderView4.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void imgBtnView_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton btndetails = sender as ImageButton;
            GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)btndetails.NamingContainer;
            lblOrgID.Text = gvrow.Cells[0].Text;
            lblOrgName.Text = gvrow.Cells[1].Text;
            lblOrgDescription.Text = gvrow.Cells[2].Text;
            lblOrgAddress.Text = gvrow.Cells[3].Text;
            lblOrgZipCode.Text = gvrow.Cells[4].Text;
            lblOrgCountry.Text = gvrow.Cells[5].Text;
            lblOrgEmail.Text = gvrow.Cells[6].Text;
            lblOrgPhoneNo.Text = gvrow.Cells[7].Text;
            lblOrgWebsite.Text = gvrow.Cells[8].Text;
            lblOwnerEmail.Text = gvrow.Cells[9].Text;
            lblActiveStatus.Text = gvrow.Cells[10].Text;

            this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        }

        //Whether a particular data needs to be deleted or not
        protected void imgBtnDelete_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton btndetails = sender as ImageButton;
            GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)btndetails.NamingContainer;
            Session["OrgDeleteRecord"] = gvrow.Cells[0].Text;
            lblOrgDelete.Text = gvrow.Cells[1].Text;
            
            this.ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
        }

        //Clicked OK to delete a record from the DB and Grid
        protected void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strDeleteRecord = (string)Session["OrgDeleteRecord"];
            int intOrgRowIndex = (int)Session["OrgRowIndex"];
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = (DataTable)Session["OrgDataSet"];

            DataRow[] rows;
            rows =  dt.Select("OrgID='" + strDeleteRecord + "'");
            foreach (DataRow row in rows)
                dt.Rows.Remove(row);

            grdOrgListData.DataSource = dt;
            grdOrgListData.DataBind();

            Session["OrgDataSet"] = dt;
        }
       

        protected void imgBtnEdit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        protected void imgBtnActive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       protected void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strDeleteRecord = (string)Session["OrgDeleteRecord"];
        int intOrgRowIndex = (int)Session["OrgRowIndex"];
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)Session["OrgDataSet"];

        DataRow[] rows;
        rows =  dt.Select("OrgID='" + strDeleteRecord + "'");
        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
            dt.Rows.Remove(row);

        //here you can call your LoadGridData() After Delete;

        this.LoadGridData();

        Session["OrgDataSet"] = dt;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look at my code....... but Same ERROR as before......... I am receiving ERROR at below line in CustomersGridView_RowDataBound if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[10].Text) == 0)

May be because e.Row.Cells[10].Text is not getting value appropriately when data bound after deleting.

Answer (score 0):

This error was because I made some of the columns in GridView invisible. First I made visible; then data binded; then made invisible again. That is working perfectly.

```
        //Making all columns in GridView visible to rebind the data 
        //Otherwise DataBind() will not work as there is checking at ActiveStatus[].
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            grdOrgListData.Columns[i].Visible = true;

        grdOrgListData.DataSource = ds;
        grdOrgListData.DataBind();

        grdOrgListData.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        grdOrgListData.Columns[2].Visible = false;
        grdOrgListData.Columns[3].Visible = false;
        grdOrgListData.Columns[4].Visible = false;
        grdOrgListData.Columns[7].Visible = false;
        grdOrgListData.Columns[9].Visible = false;
        grdOrgListData.Columns[10].Visible = false;
```